# In a Google image sitemap, is the title or the caption more important?

Tags: google, sitemap

Here is the document about [google image sitemaps](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636). Of `<image:caption>` and `<image:title>`, which is more important? If I have only one description of this image, which part is better to be put in? I mean, put the description in `<image:caption>`, leave `<image:title>` blank, or put the description in `<image:title>`, leave `<image:caption>` blank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those tags are entirely different–and fairly self-explanatory–things. The difference between them isn't really importance, but purpose. Your descriptions will fit best in the `image:caption` element. Reserve `image:title` for if/when you have *actual titles*, such as a named piece of artwork. Some images don't have titles at all, and that's fine; it's why the element is optional. That's not a reason to cram an entirely different kind of data into it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
 <url>
   <loc>http://www.couldserver.com/somepage.html</loc>
   <image:image>
     <image:loc>http://couldserver.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
     <image:title>a pretty car</image:title>
     <image:caption>a car description</image:caption>
   </image:image>
 </url> 
</urlset>
```

This the right usage, put `image:title` and `image:caption` inside `image:image`!
It's better to use both tags.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  He is asking which is more important when he doesn't *have* text for both.   You just say to use both.

Comment: In line 9 is a mistake - please close with an caption, no with title.